# UMP test for hypergeometric distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, likelihood-ratio, hypergeometric-distribution

$P(X=x|N,D,n)=\frac{^DC_x \times ^{(N-D)}C_{(n-x)}}{^NC_n}$

Now, I was trying to test for $H_0:D\le D_0$ vs $H_1:D>D_0$ using likelihood ratio test.

But to find the maximum likelihood estimate of $D,$ the terms are in $^DC_x$ form, so I could not proceed further.

Can anyone provide me how to find the estimate of $D$ or provide some other test for this problem?

Comment: You can look at $\dfrac{P(X=x\mid N,D+1,n)}{P(X=x\mid N,D,n)}$ with lots of cancellations

Comment: @Henry why should we look at that term ? Can you explain ?

Comment: You are looking at how the likelihood changes as $D$ changes, but cannot take the derivative as $D$ can only be an integer.  So you might instead take the ratio of successive terms to give you an idea of its behaviour

Comment: @Henry okay . i get it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $X\sim \operatorname{HyperGeo}(N,D,n) . $

We need to find (if it exists) the UMP test of $\mathcal H_0: D\leq D_0$ vs $\mathcal H_1: D> D_0.$

What should be the approach to tackle such problem, in general?

Possible line of approach:

$\bullet$ Check whether the family of distributions possesses the property of Monotone Likelihood Ratio (MLR) through any statistic $T(\mathbf x). $

$\bullet$ If so, hypotheses like above can be assessed via theorem of Karlin-Rubin which does show the existence of a UMP level $\alpha$ test.

---

Edit: How to calculate the MLE of $D: ~\hat D?$ One needs to solve
$ \mathcal L( D|\mathbf x) \geq \mathcal L( D-1|\mathbf x) .$ From this, one would get a bound on $D.$ Can this be MLE of $D?$

Comment: I was trying to find maximum likelihood ratio but for that I need a mle of the likelihood function . Can you tell how to find the that estimate for hypergeometric distribution ?

Comment: @Andrew741 I have edited. Hope you can make insight of the hint.

Comment: +1 For providing an outline and leaving the formal work for OP.